# Test returns ArgumentError

Tags: ruby

I meant to type `test` and receive `nil`. However I receive this instead:

```
ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (0 for 2..3)
    from (irb):15:in `test'
    from (irb):15
    from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone know if I need to fix something?

Comment: Where's the code that you're working with? Post it so we can take a look.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may be what you're after:

```
2.3.0 :003 > puts 'test'
test
 => nil
```